# How to know when a subview becomes its coordinates in its parent view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to find a way for the following problem: If I add views (annotation views) to a parent view (map view) I can't have their positions immediately but at some point in the furute (when the view becomes visible, makes it layout, whatever ...). I would like to be triggered if the position of my subviews becomes available (I mean `sview1.center.x`, `sview1.center.y`). Is there a smart way?

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibile way:

Use the UIView's `subviews` function (it returns an NSArray containig all the subviews) and enumerate through it and check all the views

Comment: Hmm ... but this way has nothing to do with notifications or triggering.

Comment: If the view's position is enabled, then send a message.
If you want to check that frquently, use a timer